# How can I display images using a image URL in carousel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, twitter-bootstrap

I am not able to display images in carousel through image URL(JSON data). I am trying to set attribute using attr() in jquery but cannot achieve desired result. Here is my code:

```
<div class="col-md-8">
            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <!-- Indicators -->
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                </ol>

                <!-- Wrapper for slides-->
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <img src="" alt="myimage1" style="width: 100%">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h3>Your news title</h3>
                            <p>news in short</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="" alt="myimage2" style="width: 100%">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h3>Your news title</h3>
                            <p>news in short</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="" alt="myimage3" style="width: 100%">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h3>Your news title</h3>
                            <p>news in short</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Left and Right controls -->
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

In .js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$.getJSON('https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=techcrunch&sortBy=top&apiKey=my-api-key',function(json) {
        console.log(json);
        console.log(json.articles.length);

        for(var i = 0 ;i<3;i++){  //As my carousel contains only 3 images
            $(".item").attr("src",json.articles[i].urlToImage);
        }

    });
});
```

The JSON response of API:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".item").attr("src",json.articles[i].urlToImage);
```

should be

```
$(".item img").attr("src",json.articles[i].urlToImage);
```